# I want to print different contents by layer pop-up with different buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The code I wrote now has a title with 1 attached, a title with 2 attached, and a comment with 2 attached at any time I press the button.

I don't know how to correct it because I'm writing it after looking at an example.
Among the codes written, there is `data-id`. The reason why I used this is because I asked another question and tried to graft the code that someone else gave me, but I couldn't do it and couldn't delete it when I posted it on the stackoverflow.
I want to keep as few code as possible.

```js
function dialog() {
  var dialogBox = $('.dialog'),
    dialogTrigger = $('.dialog__trigger'),
    dialogClose = $('.dialog__close'),
    dialogTitle = $('.dialog__title'),
    dialogContent = $('.dialog__content');

  dialogTrigger.on('click', function(e) {
    dialogBox.toggleClass('dialog--active');
    e.stopPropagation();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
  });

  dialogClose.on('click', function() {
    dialogBox.removeClass('dialog--active');
  });

  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
      dialogBox.removeClass('dialog--active');
    }
  });

  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if (
      $(e.target).is(dialogBox) === false &&
      $(e.target).is(dialogTitle) === false &&
      $(e.target).is(dialogContent) === false
    ) {
      dialogBox.removeClass('dialog--active');
    }
  });
}

$(function() {
  dialog();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: #333333;
  font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.dialog__trigger,
.dialog__action {
  border: 3px solid #333333;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-out;
  transition: all 150ms ease-out;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.dialog__trigger:hover,
.dialog__action:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.4);
}

.dialog__trigger:focus,
.dialog__action:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.dialog__trigger:active,
.dialog__action:active {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-3px);
  transform: translateY(-3px);
}

.dialog {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 35%);
  top: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.4);
  border: 3px solid #333333;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 180ms ease-in;
  transition: all 180ms ease-in;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .dialog {
    width: 90%;
    left: calc(50% - 45%);
  }
}

.dialog .dialog--active {
  top: 10%;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
  transition: all 250ms ease-out;
}

.dialog .dialog__close {
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: color 150ms ease;
  transition: color 150ms ease;
}

.dialog .dialog__close:hover {
  color: #E74C3C;
}

.dialog .dialog__title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333333;
}

.dialog .dialog__content {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="dialog__trigger" data-id="#dialog1">OPEN1</button>
<div class="dialog" id="dialog1" title="Dialog Title">
  <span class="dialog__close">x</span>
  <h2 class="dialog__title">TITLE1</h2>
  <p class="dialog__content">CONTENT1</p>
</div>
<button class="dialog__trigger" data-id="#dialog2">OPEN2</button>
<div class="dialog" id="dialog2" title="Dialog Title">
  <span class="dialog__close">x</span>
  <h2 class="dialog__title">TITLE2</h2>
  <p class="dialog__content">CONTENT2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question isn't at all clear. You've just vaguely described the page content, not the problem you're having or what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first reason your code wasn't working because of a problem in a CSS rule: `.dialog .dialog--active {}` won't match the element you want it to, because both classnames are on the same DOM element; instead this should be `.dialog.dialog--active {}` (no space).

But this triggers both dialogs from both buttons; so you also need a javascript change to identify the specific elements for each button. You could use specific IDs and a different function for each button, or you could use the elements' relative position in the document:

`$(this).next('.dialog').addClass('dialog--active');`

Both fixes are shown below:

```js
function dialog() {
  var dialogBox = $('.dialog'),
    dialogTrigger = $('.dialog__trigger'),
    dialogClose = $('.dialog__close'),
    dialogTitle = $('.dialog__title'),
    dialogContent = $('.dialog__content');

  dialogTrigger.on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).next('.dialog').addClass('dialog--active');
    e.stopPropagation();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
  });

  dialogClose.on('click', function() {
    dialogBox.removeClass('dialog--active');
  });

  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
      dialogBox.removeClass('dialog--active');
    }
  });

  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if (
      $(e.target).is(dialogBox) === false &&
      $(e.target).is(dialogTitle) === false &&
      $(e.target).is(dialogContent) === false
    ) {
      dialogBox.removeClass('dialog--active');
    }
  });
}

$(function() {
  dialog();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: #333333;
  font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.dialog__trigger,
.dialog__action {
  border: 3px solid #333333;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-out;
  transition: all 150ms ease-out;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.dialog__trigger:hover,
.dialog__action:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.4);
}

.dialog__trigger:focus,
.dialog__action:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.dialog__trigger:active,
.dialog__action:active {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-3px);
  transform: translateY(-3px);
}

.dialog {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 35%);
  top: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.4);
  border: 3px solid #333333;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 180ms ease-in;
  transition: all 180ms ease-in;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .dialog {
    width: 90%;
    left: calc(50% - 45%);
  }
}

.dialog.dialog--active {
  top: 10%;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
  transition: all 250ms ease-out;
}

.dialog .dialog__close {
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: color 150ms ease;
  transition: color 150ms ease;
}

.dialog .dialog__close:hover {
  color: #E74C3C;
}

.dialog .dialog__title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333333;
}

.dialog .dialog__content {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="dialog__trigger">OPEN1</button>
<div class="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
  <span class="dialog__close">x</span>
  <h2 class="dialog__title">TITLE1</h2>
  <p class="dialog__content">CONTENT1</p>
</div>
<button class="dialog__trigger">OPEN2</button>
<div class="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
  <span class="dialog__close">x</span>
  <h2 class="dialog__title">TITLE2</h2>
  <p class="dialog__content">CONTENT2</p>
</div>
```

But I would suggest a lot of other changes. Your code includes some obsolete CSS rules, follows some bad practices (it's not a great idea to handle every event from the `document` node for example) and is just generally very overcomplicated.

Here's a cleaner example:

```js
$('.dialog__trigger').on('click', function() {
  // Add the 'active' class to the next dialog element.
  // (You could also just use .show() here)
  $(this).next('.dialog').addClass('dialog--active');
});

$('body, .dialog__close').on('click', function() {
  // remove the 'active' class from any element, when either the
  // body or a close button is clicked.
  $('.dialog--active').removeClass('dialog--active');
});

$('#container').on('click', function(e) {
  // prevent click events bubbling up to the body
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  // handle the escape key
  if (e.keyCode === 27) {
    $('.dialog--active').removeClass('dialog--active');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: #333333;
  font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.dialog__trigger,
.dialog__action {
  border: 3px solid #333333;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  transition: all 150ms ease-out;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.dialog__trigger:hover,
.dialog__action:hover {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.4);
}

.dialog__trigger:focus,
.dialog__action:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.dialog__trigger:active,
.dialog__action:active {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
}

.dialog {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 35%);
  top: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.4);
  border: 3px solid #333333;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 180ms ease-in;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .dialog {
    width: 90%;
    left: calc(50% - 45%);
  }
}

.dialog.dialog--active {
  top: 10%;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 250ms ease-out;
}

.dialog .dialog__close {
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  transition: color 150ms ease;
}

.dialog .dialog__close:hover {
  color: #E74C3C;
}

.dialog .dialog__title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333333;
}

.dialog .dialog__content {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <button class="dialog__trigger">OPEN1</button>
  <div class="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
    <span class="dialog__close">x</span>
    <h2 class="dialog__title">TITLE1</h2>
    <p class="dialog__content">CONTENT1</p>
  </div>
  <button class="dialog__trigger">OPEN2</button>
  <div class="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
    <span class="dialog__close">x</span>
    <h2 class="dialog__title">TITLE2</h2>
    <p class="dialog__content">CONTENT2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answers and feedback.
The code you suggested was easier to see.
It runs on Run code snippets, so I tried moving it to my "ide" but it doesn't work. I think the Js declaration was wrong.
`<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="query.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="query.js">
    </script>
</head>`
I'm really sorry, but please check if there's a problem with this method.

Comment: You're including angular and jQuery and something called "query.js"; you should only need jQuery for the above code.  (I've only just now noticed that angular was being imported into the original code as well; unless you're using it for other purposes you can remove it, angular is a completely different framework from jQuery.)

Comment: As for what is causing your code to not work, I can't really say; first thing would be to check the browser console for error messages.

Comment: I'm using an opera browser, and I've checked for browser console errors. However, it is a problem because there is nothing wrong with the error. If there was an error, I would have searched it. :(
I'm sorry for my lack of understanding.